# Determine size of LVM thin snapshots

Tags: lvm

When using LVM thin volumes, tools like `lvs` no longer display the data size (`Data%` column) of individual snapshots. This makes sense as data size has a somewhat murky definition when using thin snapshots. However I would still like to determine how much space my snapshots are using.

I would like to be able to determine the number of extents in use by a snapshot which are not shared with any other volume (both snapshots and the origin). This would effectively tell me how much space would be gained by deleting the snapshot.
I would also like to be able to determine the number of extents not shared with the origin volume, but may be shared with other snapshot volumes. This would tell me how much the origin volume has changed since the snapshot was taken.

Is there any way to accomplish this?

Comment: See also duplicate question with no answer on serverfault: https://serverfault.com/questions/733150/figure-out-the-used-space-on-the-snapshot-thin-volume